# Как записать архив в переменную и потом её сосчитать на C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Я упаковываю файл/папку в архив и отдаю пользователю архив при скачивании.
Получаются следующие действия:

> 1.Создание архива и запись его на диск.
>   2.Загрузка архива с диска и отправка пользователю.
>   3.Удаление архива с диска.

Так я создаю архив

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zipPath, ZipName);
```

И так выдаю клиенту и потом удалить надо

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File(FilePath, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, "File.zip");           
}
```

Вопрос. Можно ли писать архив в переменную и потом загружать с неё и в конце она просто очищается, минуя запись на диск*?
*(*считая, что оперативной памяти достаточно)*

Comment: У вас .NET какая? Если не ошибаюсь, то для сжатия можно использовать `MemoryStream`. Насколько я помню, класс для работы с ZIP в .NET 4.5 вполне себе позволяет такое, а уже пользователю отдаете полученный поток MemoryStream.

Comment: Или, как вариант, читать из потока в массив байт (`byte[]`) и отдавать переменную с массивом.

Comment: @BlackWitcher Net 4.5. А Вы примеры не видели?

Comment: Что смог - написал в ответе. Надеюсь, пригодится и поможет.

Answer (score 2):

В .NET 4.5 добавлена библиотека [System.IO.Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx) для работы с сжатием данных (архивацией), в том числе работать можно и с потоками. Попробуйте, например, так:

```
//Создаем новый поток в памяти
FileStream fZip = new MemoryStream();
//Создаем выходной ZIP-поток
ZipOutputStream zipOStream = new ZipOutputStream(fZip);
//Сканируем директорию sourceDirectory в поисках файлов
var allfiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
//Обрабатываем каждый найденный файл
foreach (FileInfo fi in allfiles)
{
   //Добавляем новый элемент архива
   ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry((fi.Name));
   zipOStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
   //Открываем файл как поток и читаем его в ZIP-поток   
   FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fi.FullName);
   try
   {
       byte[] transferBuffer[1024];
       do
       {
           bytesRead = fs.Read(transferBuffer, 0, transferBuffer.Length);
           zipOStream.Write(transferBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
       }
       while (bytesRead > 0);
   }
   finally
   {
       fs.Close();
   }
}
//Закрываем наш получившийся ZIP-поток, теперь можно отдавать его клиенту.
zipOStream.Finish();
zipOStream.Close();
```

Еще вариант:

```
var allfiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   //Создаем поток для архива в памяти.
   using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
   {
      foreach (var f in allfiles)
      {
          var demoFile = archive.CreateEntry(f);
      }
   }
   memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   //Теперь можно скопировать в файловый поток, например (будет zip-архив) или отдать поток клиенту:
   //memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
   }
}
```

Вариант с архивом из массива байт как раз для ASP .NET MVC приведен на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17220824/6935496). Позволю себе скопировать код сюда:

```
using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    //Create an archive and store the stream in memory.
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false)) {
        foreach (var caseAttachmentModel in caseAttachmentModels) {
            //Create a zip entry for each attachment
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(caseAttachmentModel.Name);

            //Get the stream of the attachment
            using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(caseAttachmentModel.Body)) {
                using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open()) {
                    //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                    originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };
}
```